# Changing name does not work when I add a a definition to do it

Tags: python, class

```
"""
File: student.py
Resources to namage a student's name and test scores.
"""


class Student(object):
    """Represents a student"""

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        """Constructor creates a Student with a given name
        and number of scores and sets all scores to )."""
        self._name = name
        self._scores = []
        for count in range(number):
            self._scores.append(0)

    def getName(self):
        """Returns students name"""
        return self._name

    def setScore(self, i, score):
        """Resets the ith score, counting from 1"""
        self._scores[i - 1] = score

    def getScore(self, i):
        """Returns the ith score, counting from 1"""
        return self._scores[i - 1]

    def getAverage(self):
        """Returns the average scores"""
        return sum(self._scores) / len(self._scores)

    def getHighScore(self,):
        """Returns the highest score"""
        return max(self._scores)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of the student"""
        return "Name: " + self._name + "\nScores: " + " ".join(map(str, self._scores))
```

Iam trying the change the name but it is not working with this:

```
def chageName(self, name):
    name = self._name
```

Comment: It should have been `self._name = name`

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, change your method so it changes the object attribute:

```
def changeName(self, name):
    self._name = name
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked a specific question and got a specific answer.  If you are interested you may also want to consider, dare I say, making your code more "Pythonic." While "Pythonic" is, to some extent, in the eye of the beholder, there are some recurring rules of thumb:

- "It is better to beg forgiveness than ask permission" - Using getters/setters is less common in Python than in Java, for example, in part due to this philosophy and in part due to the ability to transparently apply getter/setter properties should the need arise.  This also has the beneficial effect of simplifying your code.
- "Snake-Case" (e.g., one_var) is the preferred way to name variables and functions versus "Camel-Case" (e.g., oneVar).
- "There should be one— and preferably only one —obvious way to do it."  In this case, list comprehensions, once you get used to them, are the preferred way to build lists over for loops (e.g., `self.scores`).

Example:

```
from statistics import mean

class Student:
    """Represents a student"""

    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        """Initializer instantiates a Student with a given name
        and number of scores and sets all scores to )."""
        self.name = name
        
        self.scores = [
            one_score
            for one_score in scores
        ]

    @property
    def average_score(self):
        """Returns the average scores"""
        return round(mean(self.scores), 2)

    @property
    def high_score(self):
        """Returns the highest score"""
        return max(self.scores)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of the student"""
        return "Name: " + self.name + "\nScores: " + " ".join(str(self.scores))
```